# JPA @Version behaviour

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

im using JPA2 with Hibernate 3.6.x

I have made a simple testing on the @Version.

Let's say we have 2 entities,

1. Entity Team has a List of Player Entities, bidirectional relationship, lazy fetchtype, cascade-type All
2. Both entities have @Version

And here are the scenarios :

1. Whenever a modification is made to one of the team/player entity, the team/player's version will be increased when flushed/commited (version on the modified record is increased).
2. Adding a new player entity to team's collection using persist, the entity the team's version will be assigned after persist (adding a new entity, that new entity will got it's version).
3. Whenever an addition/modification/removal is made to one of the player entity, the team's version will be increased when flushed/commited. (add/modify/remove child record, parent's version got increased also)

I can understand the number 1 and 2, but the number 3, i dont understand, why the team's version got increased ?

And that makes me think of other questions :

1. What if i got Parent <-> child <-> granchildren relation ship. Will an addition or modification on the grandchildren increase the version of child and parent ?
2. In scenario number 2, how can i get the version on the team before it's commited, like perhaps by using flush ? Is it a recommended way to get the parent's version after we do something to the child[s] ?

---

Here's a code sample from my experiment, proving that when ReceivingGoodDetail is the owning side, and the version got increased in the ReceivingGood after flushing. Sorry that this use other entities, but ReceivingGood is like the Team, ReceivingGoodDetail is like the Player. 1 ReceivingGood/Team, many ReceivingGoodDetail/Player.

```
/*
Hibernate: select receivingg0_.id as id9_14_, receivingg0_.creationDate as creation2_9_14_, .. too long
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id0_4_, product0_.creationDate as creation2_0_4_, .. too long
before persisting the new detail, version of header is : 14
persisting the detail 1c9f81e1-8a49-4189-83f5-4484508e71a7
printing the size of the header : 
Hibernate: select details0_.receivinggood_id as receivi13_9_8_, details0_.id as id8_, details0_.id as id10_7_, .. too long
7
after persisting the new detail, version of header is : 14
Hibernate: insert into ReceivingGoodDetail (creationDate, modificationDate, usercreate_id, usermodify_id, version, buyQuantity, buyUnit, internalQuantity, internalUnit, product_id, receivinggood_id, supplierLotNumber, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update ReceivingGood set creationDate=?, modificationDate=?, usercreate_id=?, usermodify_id=?, version=?, purchaseorder_id=?, supplier_id=?, transactionDate=?, transactionNumber=?, transactionType=?, transactionYearMonth=?, warehouse_id=? where id=? and version=?
after flushing, version of header is now : 15
    */
public void addDetailWithoutTouchingCollection() {
    String headerId = "3b373f6a-9cd1-4c9c-9d46-240de37f6b0f";
    ReceivingGood receivingGood = em.find(ReceivingGood.class, headerId);

    // create a new detail
    ReceivingGoodDetail receivingGoodDetailCumi = new ReceivingGoodDetail();
    receivingGoodDetailCumi.setBuyUnit("Drum");
    receivingGoodDetailCumi.setBuyQuantity(1L);
    receivingGoodDetailCumi.setInternalUnit("Liter");
    receivingGoodDetailCumi.setInternalQuantity(10L);
    receivingGoodDetailCumi.setProduct(getProduct("b3e83b2c-d27b-4572-bf8d-ac32f6de5eaa"));
    receivingGoodDetailCumi.setSupplierLotNumber("Supplier Lot 1");
    decorateEntity(receivingGoodDetailCumi, getUser("3978fee3-9690-4377-84bd-9fb05928a6fc"));
    receivingGoodDetailCumi.setReceivingGood(receivingGood);

    System.out.println("before persisting the new detail, version of header is : " + receivingGood.getVersion());

    // persist it
    System.out.println("persisting the detail " + receivingGoodDetailCumi.getId());
    em.persist(receivingGoodDetailCumi);

    System.out.println("printing the size of the header : ");
    System.out.println(receivingGood.getDetails().size());

    System.out.println("after persisting the new detail, version of header is : " + receivingGood.getVersion());

    em.flush();

    System.out.println("after flushing, version of header is now : " + receivingGood.getVersion());
}
```

Comment: Which is the owning side of the relationship? Player or Team?

Comment: Im only assuming the term 'owning side' means the side that has the collection of entities. Team has one to many relationship with Player. So i think this means Team is the owning side, since it owns a collection of players.

Comment: Owning side is, in short, which part is the one which you actively change. Basically, a "Person has many books", and not "A book has many people". In your case, a "Team is made of Players". So, you'd change a player's team, and not the team's players (player.setTeam() instead of team.getPlayers()...setTeam())

Comment: By the way: axtavt actually answers your question. I believe that he also thinks that the owning side is Player.

Comment: @partenon: Thank you for the explanation. Will check my testing code again tomorrow in my office pc. My code revolves around fetching the player entity from EM, and then modify some properties in the player's entity, and then make use of team.addPlayer(player), whose main processes basically removes the player if it exists in the collection, and adds it again to the collection, and also set the player's team. Perhaps i dont really need to add it again into the list to avoid version increase in the team record, considering the player entity is already managed when i got it from the EM.

Comment: Based on this (and previous) questions from you, I really recommend "Java Persistence with Hibernate". Hibernate is a powerful tool, and deeply understanding how it works will help you in the long term :-)

Comment: @partenon : Thank you partenon for the suggestion, will read the book as soon as i have the time. So far i've been learning this from "hibernate made easy" and "pro jpa 2" and of course from stackoverflow fellas :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Hibernate.

JPA Specification says:

> All non-relationship fields and properties and all relationships owned by the entity are
>   included in version checks

However, Hibernate also increments version after change of non-owned relationship properties (whereas, for example, EclipseLink doesn't do it). This behaviour can be disabled by setting `@OptimisticLock(exclude = true)` on the property.

Note that it's only applicable to changes of relationship property itself, not to changes in the state of referenced objects, so that version of parent wouldn't be changes due to changes in collection of grandchildren.

Comment: @axtavt : Good to know that. Do you happen to know if this was already reported to Hibernate team?

Comment: @axtavt: "However, Hibernate also increments version after change of non-owned relationship properties" <-- does this mean that the team's version shouldnt get increased when it's player entity is modified ?

Comment: @Albert: `Team`'s version shoudn't be increased if `Player` is the owning side, but should be if `Team` is the owning side. That's how it's specified and how EclipseLink works. However Hibernate increments version in both cases.

Comment: @partenon: I couldn't find it. I think I'll report it if nobody can provide better explanation of this behaviour here.

Comment: @axtavt: Ah i see. I think in my code, i call team.addPlayer(player) which basically puts the player into the collection again, and also set the player's team to the current instance of the team. Perhaps that's why the team's version got increased, because we have some operations on it's collection of players ? And the player's version is increased also because the record is modified.

Comment: @Albert: Yes, without modification of collection version shouldn't be increased.

Comment: @axtavt: added some codes in the original post, proving the version increase on both sides.

Comment: @axtavt: Hello again.. can i ask for the URL for your bug report ? Thanks !