# version property not getting reflected after inserting new instance

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

When I use **em.persist()** to insert a new instance of an entity-class, generated **id** is reflected in entity-class, but the **version** property still shows null, it is not reflected in the entity-class.

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.1.

**partial entity-class code**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Version
private Long version;

public void create(Item item) {

    System.out.println("Before Creating " + item.id + ", " + item.version);
    entityManager.persist(item);
    System.out.println("After Creating " + item.id + ", " + item.version);
}
```

Statement after **persist()** displays item.id shows **1**, but item.version shows **null**, even though, if I check in database it is **1**.

Is it supposed to be this way, or is a bug?

Comment: See [JPA @Version behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258585/jpa-version-behaviour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`persist()` doesn't insert the entity in database. And you're not even guaranteed to have an ID assigned after `persist()` has been called.

What persist does is to make a transient entity attached to the entity manager. At flush time, the version will be assigned.

So, if you really need the new version before the transaction is committed, call `flush()` explicitely and then get the new version. But usually, it's not needed because you don't need to deal with the version field yourself, so just commit the transaction: it will cause a flush to be done, and the version will thus be assigned.

Comment: Sorry for late update! got caught in something entirely different topic!  

Yes you are right. Wonder if there is any workaround, if I need id/version before commit.  

Thanks much.